# How to process individual connected components from 3D volume in matlab?

Tags: matlab, volume

I have a 3D dataset containing multiple connected components. Using matlab, I would like to compute a certain metric for each of these components (the metric is not included in the 'regionprops' function). My question is what is the best way to do it?

The metric I would like to compute is the surface area. I know how to do this for one connected component, but I'm looking for an efficient way to do it for all components that meet a certain volume criteria.

What I have so far:

```
cc = bwconncomp(data,26); % find components
L = labelmatrix(cc); % 
stats = regionprops(data, 'area');


for i = 1:length(cc.PixelIdxList)

  if stats(i,1).Area > threshold

    a = (L==i);
    surfaceArea(i,1) = compute_surface_area(a);

  end

end
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this!

Thanks in advance, N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `arrayfun` that computes the surface area for each connected component whose area is above `threshold`.

```
idx = find([stats.Area]>threshold);
arrayfun(@(ii) compute_surface_area(L == ii), idx, 'UniformOutput', 0 )
```

Here, the `for` loop is written in a single line of code.